# Is there any package or source where i can get HTML markup validation which i can use in react project and supported on react?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am working on a project which is on react and where I want to give an option to use the HTML markup Validation by input and which is supported on react.

Is there any source or package which I can use for my project?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a npm package which can help you to validate markup -> *VALIMATE*

**The Github link**: [Documentation](https://github.com/jamesseanwright/valimate)

**Tutorial link**:  [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@jamesseanwright/automatically-validate-html-with-node-js-and-valimate-196c71a349bf)

Comment: Thanks for helping buddy.